# Did Mike Pence advocate conversion therapy for homosexuals?

Tags: politics, sexuality

It's not difficult to find image memes indicating that Mike Pence, our future vice-president for 2017-2020, advocates gay conversion therapy paid for by the government.

[image: Scaremongering meme]

Did he actually make that statement, or one reasonably interpreted as such? The source of the statement seems to be come down to an amendment to the Ryan White Care Act:

> Congress should support the reauthorization of the Ryan White Care Act only after completion of an audit to ensure that federal dollars were no longer being given to organizations that celebrate and encourage the types of behaviors that facilitate the spreading of the HIV virus. **Resources should be directed toward those institutions which provide assistance to those seeking to change their sexual behavior**.

California Lt. Gov. Gavin Newsom says that Pence "advocated for diverting taxpayer dollars to so-called conversion therapy." and [Politifact rated that statement as true](http://www.politifact.com/california/statements/2016/jul/28/gavin-newsom/true-mike-pence-advocated-conversion-therapy/) based on the text of the Ryan White Care Act. Snopes, on the other hand, [rated it as "Mixture"](http://www.snopes.com/mike-pence-supported-gay-conversion-therapy/), saying that the text did not support the assertion.

Is there a quote from Mike Pence stating that he is in favor of conversion therapy for homosexuals?

Comment: Quite honestly it sounds like Pence wanted those who had HIV or AIDs to wear a condom.

Comment: Or simply stop having all of this sex with strangers...

Comment: When you read the whole ["Strengthening the American Family"](https://web.archive.org/web/20010519165033fw_/http://cybertext.net/pence/issues.html) section and apply a bit of [close reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_reading), and maybe a touch of their notably anti-gay track record, it's pretty easy to arrive at this conclusion. I too would be curious to know if there are any more-explicit quotes on the subject, or related legislature supported, but such statements are rarely so explicit.

Comment: It looks like it's the same quote I mentioned above. Unless you know of something else on there to "close read"? So far, it all seems to come down to various people saying "... well, they don't *say* it, but we all know how that kind of person thinks, right?"

Comment: Yes, it is the origin of the quote. The context of the prior points shows a remarkably explicit anti-gay agenda, dominating the section in general. This last bullet point is the most-loaded with word games, which seem to have one meaning, but allow the author to retreat to another meaning when challenged. It's like making an anti-gay innuendo following a stream of explicitly anti-gay statements, and then say "no, I meant something else."

Comment: {nods} So basically it's a "there's no proof of this, but this is what we think" from multiple people.

Comment: More-like agreeing with what he insinuated. Maybe he said it because he actually supports it, wants those who do support it to think he does, or is completely oblivious to how inappropriate what he says is.

Comment: @KDog no, it really doesn't sound like he only wants to advocate for condom use. There are no organizations which celebrate not wearing a condom. So when Pence talks about "celebrating and encouraging the types of behaviors that facilitate the spreading of the HIV virus" in a context which also argues against the rights of LGBT people, it is not a reach to conclude that he is talking about gay sex, and that that is the sexual behavior which should be changed.

Comment: And of course Pence doesn't actually think that condoms are good at preventing HIV: "condoms are a very, very poor protection against sexually transmitted diseases".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No.

Some are misconstruing the phrase "change their sexual behavior" in the sentence "Resources should be directed toward those institutions which provide assistance to those seeking to change their sexual behavior" found on his 2000 website.

The true meaning can be ascertained from Pence's 2 February 2008 [speech](https://votesmart.org/public-statement/321991/pence-delivers-policy-speech-at-ball-state-university-on-global-hivaids-funding#.WCUINrCV45s) at Ball State University, Muncie, IN.

...

> Currently within PEPFAR [President's Emergency Plan for AIDS Relief], these pivotal provisions exist in forms such as the ABC Model, which stands for **Abstinence, Be faithful, and Consistent and Correct Condom use**. It is absolutely essential that we preserve these prevention methods that focus on **behavioral change**. Working with **faith-based and non-governmental organizations** on the local level, in particular through the ABC Model, has produced undeniable results.

....

> It is not enough to send billions of dollars to Africa without sending values-based techniques that work to fight the spread of HIV/AIDS by **changing behavior**.

...

> Last week when the President called for continued support for this very important initiative in his final State of the Union address, he insisted that Congress must "maintain the principles that have **changed behavior** and made this program successful." The **current draft of this reauthorization** is no longer the program envisioned by the President and embraced by Congress. Under the new bill, PEPFAR would no longer be a program focused solely on prevention and treatment of HIV/AIDS. Instead, it would be converted to a program that, with increased funding, could take lives through abortion rather than save lives through prevention and medication. PEPFAR is a successful program that is under attack.

...

(emphasis added)

Mike Pence used similar terminology in a 24 July 2008 [press release](https://votesmart.org/public-statement/364340/hails-passage-of-global-aids-relief-bill#.WCW6YbCV45s):

> ...We cannot send billions of dollars to Africa without sending values-based safeguards and techniques that work to fight the spread of HIV/AIDS by **changing behavior**.
>
> Within the current version the Global AIDS bill that the Senate recently passed, these pivotal provisions exist in the form of a requirement to provide balanced funding for prevention activities for sexual transmission of HIV/AIDS,'and to ensure that **abstinence and faithfulness programs** are implemented and funded in a meaningful and equitable way.' This is enforced by requiring the Global AIDS Coordinator to report to the appropriate Congressional committee if **funding for abstinence, delay of sexual debut, monogamy, or fidelity programs** drops bellow [sic] 50 percent of the total sexual prevention program funding.
>
> It was essential that we preserve these prevention methods that focus on **behavioral change**, and that we work with **faith-based and non-governmental organizations at the local level, in particular through the ABC Model**, which has produced undeniable results. ...

(emphasis added)

For more information on the ABC model see [Abstinence, be faithful, use a condom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstinence,_be_faithful,_use_a_condom)

Comment: I'm having a very hard time seeing these as talking about the same thing in the context of the surrounding text in the year 2000. What kind of "institutions" would he be talking about that "focus on behavioral change"?

Comment: He also used similar language in Congress while discussing funding for of AIDS prevention programs, asking to fund ABC programs in [2003](https://www.congress.gov/congressional-record/2003/5/1/house-section/article/H3574-5) and [2008](https://www.congress.gov/amendment/110th-congress/house-amendment/973/text). (Well, he advocates strongly in favor of the A and B, less so the C, but same "getting people to change their sexual 
behavior" idea.)

Comment: This doesn't really contradict the meme. Supporting one piece of legislation does not necessarily imply that he opposes another. Politicians have also been known to change their minds, especially after 16 years.

Comment: Just to clarify; I believe the meme is probably a hoax. This post is just not enough to refute it.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara the legislation needed reauthorized every 4 years, that's why he is talking about it again in 2008.  The kind of institutions are discussed here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3178341/ (with the understanding that Pence does support using condoms)

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara like the speech says: "faith-based and non-governmental organizations on the local level, in particular through the ABC Model", those institutions that promote Abstinence, Being faithful, and using Condoms

Comment: @JørgenFogh "Supporting one piece of legislation does not necessarily imply that he opposes another." that's true, but there wasn't any  legislation or proposed legislation involving gay conversion therapy.  He is talking about the domestic (Ryan White Care Act) and corresponding global version.  The government website presents them together "Ryan White & Global HIV/AIDS programs" http://hab.hrsa.gov/